# JS funcion que retorne un valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Estoy haciendo una función en JS que recibe ciertos parámetros y retorna un valor pero la variable a pesar de cambiar en cuando se cumple alguna de las condiciones no se cambia a la hora de retornarla, siempre arroja en la consola que es undefined.

Aquí el código.

```
function evaluarDisponibilidad(id_ps, day, time_init, time_end)
{

 var result;
 var data = $.getJSON('/admin/section_professor_consult/'+id_ps+'',function(data){ 

  if (data.length > 0)
  {
    $.each(data, function(idx, elem){
      daySection = elem.day;

      time_initSection = parseFloat(elem.time_init).toFixed(2);
      time_endSection = parseFloat(elem.time_end).toFixed(2);

      time_init = parseFloat(time_init).toFixed(2);
      time_end = parseFloat(time_init).toFixed(2);
      if (day == daySection){
        console.log("Entre en el dia "+day);

        if ((time_init > time_initSection) && (time_init < time_endSection)){
          console.log("Entre en time init"+time_init);
          result = 1;

        } else if((time_end > time_endSection) && (time_end < time_endSection)){
          console.log("este en el time end"+time_end);
          result = 1;

        } else if (time_init == time_initSection){
          console.log("mismo time init "+time_init);
          result = 1;

        } else if (time_end == time_endSection){
          console.log("mismo time end"+time_end);
          result = 1;
        }
      }
    });
  } 
 });
 console.log(result);
 //return result; 
}
```

Haciendo una impresión de consola con valores que cumplan condiciones ingresa en el ciclo y en cualquiera de los condicionales, pero una vez que sale de esto el valor de result vuelve a ser undefined.

Comment: Es por que `$.getJSON` es **asíncrono**, por lo tanto no tiene control de cuando obtendrá respuesta dicha petición.

Comment: Que me recomiendan para manejar ese json y verificar los condicionales.?? Gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que añadir el return dentro de $.getJSON.

Comment: Sería un return de la variable result dentro de $.getJSON.?